# Default :exclude option for Rails resource routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

A minor question:

I am using Rails for my REST API, but since it is a RESTful API I don't really need `:new` or `:edit` routes for any of my resources since people will only be interacting with this API entirely through automated JSON requests, not graphically. There's no need for a dedicated edit page, for instance.

Currently, I need to do something like this for every resource defined:

```
# routes.rb
resources :people, except: [:new, :edit]
```

It's not a big deal to have `:except` options on every resource in `/config/routes.rb`, but is there a way to define defaults so I don't have to specify this on every resource? I'd like to DRY up this code a bit, without doing something lame like passing around a local variable with default options everywhere.

More generally, can you set default options for Rails routes to follow aside from `:exclude`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[with_options](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options) for a rescue!

```
with_options(except: [:new, :edit]) do |opt|
  opt.resource :session
  opt.resource :another_resource
  opt.resources :people
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom method to draw your routes under `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper` namespace. In your `routes.rb` file, on top of the file before `Rails.application.routes.draw do` :

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper

  def draw(resource)
    resources resource, except: [:new, :edit]
  end

end

#routes start here
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  draw :people
  draw :products
  # ...rest of the routes

end
```

Now for those particular resources you can call the `draw` method as above.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem.

You can simplify access to resources to a single file

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you can have enforce the resources with a single line

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource
    ...
end
```

Defining Abilities 
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Authorizing at Controller level
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions